# Mostrar la fecha de hoy restringiendo restringiendo dias anteriores

Tags: javascript, html, html5

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que cuando entro a la vista aparezca el día actual, es decir hoy, por ejemplo, 4 de octubre de 2023 pero que no me deje seleccionar antes del 2 de octubre de 2023? Aquí está mi código, pero aquí solo se muestra. Del 2 en adelante siempre que entro a mi vista sale del 2, debería salir hoy 4, y no permitirme seleccionar dias antes del 2.

```
letMinDate = new Date('2023-10-02').toISOString().split('T')[0] document.querySelector('#start_date').min = Mindate;
```

Comment: Buenas, Pedro. Un par de apuntes: ¿no falta algún espacio y algún salto de línea ahí en tu código? Y ¿donde estás calculando o recuperando el día actual?

Comment: Hola estimado, ya lo pude solucionar, gracias!